# How can l convert tuple to integer to do some calculations?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

l have 41 years dataset including 10 columns and l m trying to plot these data with Matplotlib and l m able to plot columns without error. However , l would like to produce different kind of graphes like yearly average pcp ,monthly average pcp and yearly sum of pcp  etc. l got data from columns and l have problem with transforming these data as integer to do some calculations.

here is example dataset from Csv file:

```
date    day month   year    pcp1    pcp2    pcp3    pcp4    pcp5    pcp6
1.01.1979   1   1   1979    0.431   2.167   9.375   0.431   2.167   9.375
2.01.1979   2   1   1979    1.216   2.583   9.162   1.216   2.583   9.162
3.01.1979   3   1   1979    4.041   9.373   23.169  4.041   9.373   23.169
4.01.1979   4   1   1979    1.799   3.866   8.286   1.799   3.866   8.286
5.01.1979   5   1   1979    0.003   0.051   0.342   0.003   0.051   0.342
6.01.1979   6   1   1979    2.345   3.777   7.483   2.345   3.777   7.483
7.01.1979   7   1   1979    0.017   0.031   0.173   0.017   0.031   0.173
8.01.1979   8   1   1979    5.061   5.189   43.313  5.061   5.189   43.313
```

here is my code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



with open('output813b.csv', 'r') as csvfile:

    # get number of columns
    for line in csvfile.readlines():
        array = line.split()
        first_item = array[0]

    num_columns = len(array)
    csvfile.seek(0)

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    included_col1 = [1]
    included_col6=[4]
    x=[]
    y=[]


    for row in reader:

            content = list(row[i] for i in included_col1)
            content2= list(row[i] for i in included_col6)
            x.append(content)
            y.append(content2)

    klm=tuple(x[i] for i in range(1,1000) if x[i]==["1979"])
    s=0
    for i in range(1,len(klm)):
        s+=y[i] #### error (for +=: 'int' and 'list')

    print (tuple(y[5])) ###example output ('2.345',)
    print (int(y [5][0])) #### error invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.345'
```

tuple in tuple ,l use `int(y[5][0])` to covert tuple to int but l got an error. l put error messages in my code. how can l fix this problem and l do some calculations. Thanks in advance

Comment: um... don't you just want to make it a `float` since it has a decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are trying to convert a decimal number into an int

If you want to use the exact value you can use `float(tuple(y[5][0]))`
Or else if you want to truncate the value you can use `int(float(tuple(y[5][0])))`

Comment: it is my mistake. l m sorry to get your time for this easy question .it slipped my mind. Thank you very much for all your effort

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be:

```
int(float(y[5][0]))
```

Instead. Since your string value has a decimal in it, you will not be able to convert directly to `int` without converting to `float` first. Keep in mind, you will lose some precision though:

```
>>> int(float('2.345'))
2
```

So if you want to use these values in calculations, you may just want to convert your tuple values to floats instead:

```
float(y[5][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got 2 different problems:

**1. s+=y[i] #### error (for +=: 'int' and 'list')**

Here are the relevant part of the code:

```
y=[]
for row in reader:
        content2= list(row[i] for i in included_col6)
        y.append(content2)
s=0
for i in range(1,len(klm)):
    s+=y[i] #### error (for +=: 'int' and 'list')
```

Then:

1. `s` is an `int`
2. `y` is a list of `content2`
3. `content2` is a `list`

Then you add to an `int` `s` a `list` `y[i]`.
That is impossible. What do you really want?

**2. #### error invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.345'**

You are trying to convert a decimal number into an int.

You should either keep the float number with `float(tuple(y[5][0]))` or convert it to an int with `int(float(tuple(y[5][0])))`

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.345 is not an integer, you need to determine what to do with the floating part. Do you want to ceil or floor it or round it?

- `int(round(float("2.345")))` gives 2
- `int(math.ceil(float("2.345")))` gives 3
- `int(math.floor(float("2.345")))` gives 2